# Error to show data from a SQL Server stored procedure called from laravel

Tags: sql-server, laravel

I have this stored procedure in SQL Server:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_buscarusuario]
    @apellido varchar (50) = NULL,
    @nombre varchar (50) = NULL,
    @nombreusuario varchar (50) = NULL,
    @email varchar(50) = NULL,
    @tipo int = NULL, 
    @error varchar(8000) = NULL OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM usuario 
    WHERE apellido = @apellido 
       OR nombre = @nombre 
       OR login = @nombreusuario 
       OR email = @email 
       OR tipo = @tipo 
END
```

This is the function in my controller in laravel:

```
public function buscarusuario(Request $request)
    {
        $apellido             =   $request->apellido;
        $nombre               =   $request->nombre;
        $nombreusuario        =   $request->nombreusuario;
        $email                =   $request->email;
        $tipo                 =   intval( $request->tipo ) ;

        $apellido           =   ($apellido   ==  NULL) ? ($apellido   =   '') :   $apellido;
        $nombre             =   ($nombre   ==  NULL) ? ($nombre   =   '') :   $nombre;
        $nombreusuario      =   ($nombreusuario   ==  NULL) ? ($nombreusuario   =   '') :   $nombreusuario;
        $email              =   ($email   ==  NULL) ? ($email   =   '') :   $email;
        $tipo               =   ($tipo   ==  NULL) ? ($tipo   =   0) :   $tipo;
    
        $data = DB::select("EXEC sp_buscarusuario '$apellido', '$nombre', '$nombreusuario', '$email', '$tipo'");

        return $data;
    }
```

[image]

The trouble is when i do the query from postman, this one shows me wrong data, in this case I run the SQL Server procedure send it `@apellido = coronel` and this one shows only a register, but in postman it shows me more.

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

In your api call, you're converting missing parameters to non-null values. For this specific case, you're converting the missing `tipo` parameter to 0. Since the select statement in your stored procedure is a bunch of `OR`ed conditions, all the extra records you've found are records where `tipo = 0`.

If your parameters are missing, you should be passing in NULLs to the stored procedure, not empty strings and 0s.